# Show that if for continuous functions $f,g$, $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in S$, where $S$ is a dense subset of $\mathbb R$, then $f=g$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, epsilon-delta

I started by considering the continuous function $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ and wanted to show $h(x)=0$ for all $x$. To do this I supposed there exists an $a\in\mathbb R$ such that $h(a)=b\ne0$. Now since $h$ is continuous at $a$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-a|<\delta$, then $|h(x)-h(a)|=|h(x)-b|<\epsilon$. So $h(x)\ne0$ in $a-\delta<x<a+\delta$. Conversely, since $S$ is a dense subset of $\mathbb R$ we know there exists an $s\in(a-\delta,a+\delta)$. Thus $h=0$ in this interval which is a contradiction. Thus, $f=g$.

I think I am missing two holes in the above proof and would much appreciate some help.

1. I wasn't sure how to use the $\delta-\epsilon$ step to then get that $h(x)\ne0$.
2. Did I actually reach a contradiction? Do I only need to find a single element in that interval where $h=0$ to achieve a contradiction or do I have to show $h=0$ for all $x$?

Comment: The set $Z=\{x:\ f(x)-g(x)=0\}$ is the inverse image of the closed set $\{0\}$ by the continuous function $f-g$. Therefore $Z$ is closed. Also $Z\supset S$.

Comment: Here you can choose $\epsilon$ to be $\frac{|h(a)|}2$.

Comment: To clarify how the argument finishes in my comment. Since $S$ is dense, the smallest closed set that contains it (its closure) is $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, $Z=\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Feng Shao says in their comment, you get to choose the $\epsilon$. Since $h$ is continuous you know that for every $\epsilon$ there is a $\delta$ so ..., and you use that by choosing a tiny $\epsilon$ that helps prove what you want to, and you know there is a $\delta$ that works. And, again as Feng said, $|h(a)|/2$ will do the job.

The contradiction should eventually be that there is an $x\in S$ so $h(x)\neq0$. You will actually end up showing that $h$ is non zero on a whole interval, but you only need one point in $S$ to get the contradiction.